# Maven for multiple deployment environment

Tags: java, maven, ant

so I want to use different environments like test and cert which has different config.properties and jndi.txt
I did put as profile with maven-antrun-plugin in pom
[image: Pom.xml file]
When I run cmd as mvn clean test -Dcucumber...... -P be-cert install, nothing happens, files do not get deleted nor copied(tried to remove 2 files manually to see if that stuff gets updated) 
Looks all good as per maven doc - https://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-using-ant.html

UPDATE: I figured it out as to change  from test to clean

Comment: do you get any error message ? can you try `${basedir}/src/test/resources/config.properties` and on the others as well

Comment: @zakariaamine yes, just tried, same thing

Comment: I don't get any error, it looks like whole task part is being ignored

Comment: did you run in debug mode ?

Comment: Where is defined your profile? Is it defined in the pom.xml or in an external profile.xml file ?

Comment: @DilneiCunha check Update for result, thx

Comment: @Vanatomas did you find the problem?

Comment: @DilneiCunha - UPDATE: I figured it out as to change from test to clean